# Is there any difference between a portable external 2.5" HD with notebook internal HD 2.5"

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, usb, external-hard-drive

I have an unused MacBook 2.5 hard drive (Toshiba) and I used it as an external hard drive using an USB to store data and plug into a Wii console to store and playing games.

But few months later the hard disk fails and is broken. I’m considering buying an external hard drive available in the market such as Seagate expansion, WD etc…

My question is, is there any technical difference between this standalone external hard drive (such as Seagate expansion etc) with an 2.5 hard drive used on notebook? I think both of them using 2.5 hd but I’d like to know if there’s any difference in terms of specs, power consumption, RPM etc…

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible unless you open up the external HDD case and check what is the actual HDD inside and their specs. They could be using off-the-shelf HDD and simply putting them into a HDD enclosure. 

There are some external HDD maker that built their own controller and embed it to the HDD so the HDD inside the external drive does not have a normal SATA port, but it just have a direct to USB port.

Comment: Most all major drive manufacturers have data sheets on their websites with this information.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to external storage most likely they'll perform in the same way since no matter what HDD you buy you will be limited by the USB speeds (5Gb/s max, or 625 MB/s). Furthermore, like [this WD KB article states](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=1704), there's no way to know what type of hard disk is inside the enclosure, unless you open it of course but by doing so you'll void the warranty.

One more important thing if you decide to go with WD then do have in mind that there are two basic portable external drive models - [WD Elements](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=4keOH6) and [WD My Passport](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=NLAesi) and they have two major differences:

- The second one is hardware encrypted and password protected while the first one is not.
- The maximum capacity of WD Elements is 2TB while WD My Passport is up to 4TB.

Hope this helps and feel free to ask any questions you may have. :)